# Analog of a theorem on equidistribution in adeles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, global-fields

Is there a reference anywhere for the analog of Theorem 6 in chapter XV of Langs *Algebraic Number Theory* for global function fields?
In my research I have been using this theorem to prove density results over number fields, and I would like to extend this to function fields.

For function fields with an infinite field of constants I have found an analog using genericity arguments, but if the field of constants is finite then this argument does not work. I think that it might be possible to prove the result using the Chebotarev density theorem (which does not suffice over number fields), but I would prefer an approach similar to the number field case.

For those without access to the book, the statement is

"Let $P$ be the set of primes. Let $\tau\colon P\rightarrow \mathbf{J}_k$ be the following map. For each $\mathfrak{p}$, select a prime element $\pi_\mathfrak{p}$ in $k_\mathfrak{p}^\times$ and let $\tau(\mathfrak{p})$ be the idele having component $1$ at all $v$ except $v_\mathfrak{p}$ at which it has component $\pi_\mathfrak{p}$. We view $P$ as filtered by the sets $P_r$ consisting of those $\mathfrak{p}$ with $N\mathfrak{p}\leq r$. Let $G$ be a compact commutative group, and let $\sigma\colon \mathbf{J}_k\rightarrow G$ be a continuous homomorphism such that $\sigma(\mathbf{J}_k^0)=G$ and whose kernel contains $k^\times$. Let $\lambda=\sigma \circ \tau$. Then $P$ is $\lambda$-equidistributed in $G$."

Here $k$ is the number field in question, $\mathbf{J}_k$ are the ideles and $\mathbf{J}_k^0$ are the ideles of norm $1$.

For my purposes it suffices if the image of $\lambda$ is were simply dense, rather than equidistributed, so if someone has a reference for this weaker statement, then I would also be interested.

Comment: Can you please state the result you want to make it easier for those without access to the book?

Comment: Sure! I have now added the statement.